# "Banco, final six, tout sur le cinq !" J'ai entendu cette phrase dans un film et je ne la comprends pas

Tags: sens, traduction

Je suis anglaise et j'apprends le français. Je suis en train de voir un film et je comprends les mots mais pas la signification de cette phrase.

Merci d'avance.

Comment: De quel film s'agit-il ? Visiblement on est dans l'univers du jeu de hasard : [banco](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/banco#Nom_commun_1), La roulette ?

Comment: Merci! Le film est "On se calme et on boit frais à Saint-Tropez", c'est une comédie.

Comment: Je ne le connais pas mais quelqu'un ici l'aura certainement vu et répondra. Les personnages doivent-être en train de jouer et ce sont des exclamations liés au jeu.

Comment: Merci! C'est le debut d'une scène mais je pense qu'ils vient de jouer en Monte Carlo.

Comment: It's Baccarat aka Punto Banco. Banco means a player wants to match the dealer's hand, they say banco.  https://ourpastimes.com/banco-card-game-rules-5920176.html Don't know the details. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les personnages viennent de jouer au Casino de Monte-Carlo.

> ***Banco !*** signifie que l'on a joué le tout pour le tout, on se met en situation de perdre tout ce qu'on a ou de faire "sauter la banque". C'est la deuxième éventualité qui s'est à priori produite.

> ***Final six*** n'est pas une expression très claire dans ce contexte, on dirait plutôt ça quand une finale, par exemple de poker, se joue entre les six joueurs restant en course. Peut être restait-il six joueurs à la table où jouaient les protagonistes.

> ***Tout sur le cinq*** est cohérent avec *Banco !*, la totalité des jetons dont dispose le joueur qui mise "tout sur le cinq" a été placée sur ce numéro. C'est une phrase typique du jeu de roulette.

Exemple:

> *Arrivé au casino, je mise **tout sur le 6**. Faites vos jeux, rien ne va plus ! Mais alors plus du tout. **Banco !** Jackpot ! Le 6 remporte la mise. La roulette a parlé.*
>
> Benjamin Castaldi, *Pour l'instant, tout va bien*, 2015

Comment: Merci beaucoup!